# no resource identifier found in takwolf layout

Tags: android

I'm getting no resource identifier found for a couple of attributes in the following layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg_lock"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">

//image
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    //textview
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:text="@string/draw_pattern"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />

//problem seems at the end of this block
<com.takwolf.android.lock9.Lock9View
    android:id="@+id/lock_9_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    app:nodeSrc="@drawable/lock_9_view_node_normal"
    app:nodeOnSrc="@drawable/lock_9_view_node_highlighted"
    app:lineColor="#ff006699"
    app:lineWidth="8dp" />


<hell.sathan.applockmasters.Custom.FlatButton
    android:id="@+id/forgetPassword"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Forget Password"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    app:buttonColor="@color/fbutton_color_carrot"
    app:cornerRadius="5dp"
    app:shadowEnabled="true"
    app:shadowHeight="2dp" />


 </LinearLayout>
```

I'm having the errors below :

> Error:(24) No resource identifier found for attribute 'nodeSrc' in
>   package
>
> Error:(24) No resource identifier found for attribute 'nodeOnSrc' in
>   package
>
> Error:(24) No resource identifier found for attribute 'lineColor' in
>   package
>
> Error:(24) No resource identifier found for attribute 'lineWidth' in
>   package

Comment: Editing for clarity, removing bold because they aren't working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put `app:lock9_` instead of `app:`.

Try to replace `app:nodeOnSrc` with `app:lock9_nodeOnSrc` for example.

In the [documentation of the library](https://github.com/TakWolf/Android-Lock9View), you have an example :

```
<com.takwolf.android.lock9.Lock9View
    android:id="@+id/lock_9_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    app:lock9_nodeSrc="@drawable/node_normal"
    app:lock9_nodeOnSrc="@drawable/node_active"
    app:lock9_nodeOnAnim="@anim/node_on_1"
    app:lock9_padding="28dp"
    app:lock9_spacing="28dp"
    app:lock9_lineColor="@color/blue_light"
    app:lock9_lineWidth="8dp"
    app:lock9_autoLink="false"
    app:lock9_enableVibrate="true"
    app:lock9_vibrateTime="20" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add dependencies `'com.takwolf.android:lock9view:0.0.11'` in Gradle.app and Sync First..

Answer (score 0):

you need to make this

```
<com.takwolf.android.lock9.Lock9View
    android:id="@+id/lock_9_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    app:lock9_nodeSrc="@drawable/node_normal"
    app:lock9_nodeOnSrc="@drawable/node_active"
    app:lock9_nodeOnAnim="@anim/node_on_1"
    app:lock9_padding="28dp"
    app:lock9_spacing="28dp"
    app:lock9_lineColor="@color/blue_light"
    app:lock9_lineWidth="8dp"
    app:lock9_autoLink="false"
    app:lock9_enableVibrate="true"
    app:lock9_vibrateTime="20" />
```

your error is you doing this

```
app:**nodeSrc**="@drawable/lock_9_view_node_normal"
```

but it's like this

```
 app:lock9_nodeSrc="@drawable/lock_9_view_node_normal"
```